# YouTube Data API v3 Is there a risk?

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, google-developers-console

Is the API key for the YouTube Data API v3 known to be at risk?

I accidentally sent the API key out Give it to someone else

Comment: Create another API key and delete the former one?

Answer (score 0):

### Public data access

Google API keys are used for accessing public data only.  The main purpose for these keys is so that google can track who is accessing their public apis.

If your key starts spamming google to much they will block your key. If you keep doing it you can get your account blocked.  I would say the only risk to someone getting a hold of your key is them using it to get your account blocked.

There may also be issues with your quota if you have other people using your key then you are all eating up the same quota.

### TOS

Beyond that there is also a note in [TOS](https://developers.googleblog.com/2014/11/subject-changes-to-google-apis-terms-of.html)

> Asking developers to make reasonable efforts to keep their private keys private and not embed them in open source projects.

Google may not be happy if you violate that and start giving your key away.

### Create a new one

If you did give it to someone else just go to [developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/) under credentials tab on the left.  You will find a list of your api keys.

[image]

Delete the one you shared and create yourself a new one. The user you accidentally sent it to will no longer be able to use it.

Comment: So I just need to delete the folder or the API file.

Comment: I have edited my question you need to do it though the Developer console